# Youtube-dl Playlist Error

Tags: command-line, youtube, youtube-dl

I got the following when I tried to update `youtube-dl`:

```
amrat@amrat-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo youtube-dl -U
[sudo] password for amrat: 
It looks like you installed youtube-dl with a package manager, pip, setup.py or a tarball. Please use that to update.
amrat@amrat-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$
```

What does it mean?

I installed the program using the terminal.

I also get this error:

```
WARNING: unable to set language: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
[youtube] ST_WC13rNJo: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 5):

You would be best to remove the Repository `youtube-dl` which rarely copes with downloading videos or upgrading itself and install instead *directly* from the developer's website:

```
sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl
sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
```

And then from time to time update your version with:

```
sudo youtube-dl -U
```

Current version reports the following:

```
andrew@ilium~$ youtube-dl --version
2016.08.01
andrew@ilium~$
```

And this version has no issues with any current YouTube videos and/or playlists that I tested it with...

**References:**

- [youtube-dl: Download](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you installed through a package manager through the terminal, then I'm assuming you used apt.

In that case, try running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to upgrade all installed packages, or use:

```
apt-get install --only-upgrade youtube-dl
```

to just upgrade the youtube-dl package.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: amrat@amrat-GA-78LMT-USB3:~$ sudo apt-get update youtube-dl
E: The update command takes no arguments

Comment: Answer edited above. Sorry, I gave you the wrong command originally.

Answer (score 1):

To fix erorrs while using youtube-dl command, try below fix:

Uninstall youtuble-dl using command : `sudo apt-get remove youtube-dl`

Install pip using command : `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Once done - install youtube-dl : `sudo pip install youtube-dl`

This worked for me, Hope it does for you as well! :)

Answer (score 0):

It means youtube-dl needs to upgraded by other means than apt or apt-get which use repo or repos which has proven to be outdated.

pip has proven to have the current version youtube-dl which is least likely to fail the download.

try `sudo -H pip install -U youtube-dl`, should show clean update of youtube-dl in terminal